# Richfaces DataTable: Filtering and retaining new input

Tags: datatable, richfaces

I'm following the jboss guide "Table Filtering" and implemented the example successfully. Then i added a new checkbox field that a user can set. When i use the filter the checkbox is resetted. Is there a way to retain the state of the checkbox?

```
<rich:dataTable value="#{capitalsBean.capitals}" var="cap" id="table">
<f:facet name="header">
    <rich:columnGroup>
        <rich:column>
            <h:outputText value="State Name" />
        </rich:column>
        <rich:column>
            <h:outputText value="State Time Zone" />
        </rich:column>
        <rich:column>
            <h:outputText value="Marked" />
        </rich:column>
    </rich:columnGroup>
</f:facet>
<rich:column filter="#{filteringBean.stateFilter}">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:inputText value="#{filteringBean.stateFilterValue}" id="input">
            <a4j:ajax event="keyup" render="table@body">
                <a4j:attachQueue  requestDelay="700"
                    ignoreDupResponses="true" />
            </a4j:ajax>
        </h:inputText>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{cap.state}" />
</rich:column>
<rich:column filterExpression="#{fn:containsIgnoreCase(cap.timeZone, filteringBean.zoneFilterValue)}">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{filteringBean.zoneFilterValue}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{filteringBean.zoneList}" />
            <a4j:ajax event="change" render="table@body" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{cap.timeZone}" />
</rich:column>
<rich:column>
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{filteringBean.marked}" disabled="false"/>
</rich:column>
```

Comment: From what I'm seeing you have multiple checkboxes bound to the same property, how do you expect that to work?

Comment: Either you're answering the wrong post or you're trolling

Comment: That's certainly a way to treat someone who is trying to help you. The `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>` is bound to `filteringBean.marked` meaning that every row is the same (and I don't see anything that would update the value). What are you trying to do? ExtendedDataTable has a built-in selection functionality.

Comment: The base code as mentioned from jboss guide: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Web_Framework_Kit/2/html/RichFaces_Component_Reference_Guide/sect-Component_Reference-Tables_and_grids-Table_filtering.html. And even though they all bound to the same property my main question is not affected from it. I want the new value, which in this case the checkbox new state to be retained when i use the filter.

Comment: You cannot retain multiple values (i.e. one row checked and another not checked) with only one variable, which is what I'm assuming you're doing. You haven't answered the main question - what is the purpose of the checkbox? What kind of functionality are trying to implement?

Comment: Yes you can, it will be one row checked and the others too since they share the same value. And as mentioned many times, following the guide and trying to implement a filter that retains values on change.